# No dump file generetaed on HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Not Working

Tags: tomcat, heap-memory

In tomcat jvm setting "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" configured but no file generates on OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Have you verified that the option is actually being applied when starting Tomcat ? Have you figured out the current working directory of the Tomcat  process ? Does tomcat have file permission to create a file in that working directory ?

Comment: Tomcat directory have permission to create files.

Comment: Ok, then you need to verify what the working directory of tomcat is. It might not be the tomcat directory itself. It might be whatever directory you happened to be in when tomcat was started, it might be something else.You probably need to tell what platform you're on, if you need help figuring that out.